# Importing NSubstitute into Unity project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, nsubstitute

I'm trying to use NSubstitute in my Unity project (Unity version 2019.2.2f1). No matter how to import it, my IDE, both Visual Studio and JetBrains Rider, would give an error when I try `using NSubstitute` saying NSubstitute is undefined.

I have tried many options and versions of NSubstitute packages (4.2.1 and 2.0.3). I also import the dll file from net35 folder of the package into a Plugins folder in my Unity project. I also tried to install the same version of NSubstitute using Nuget in the IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added NSubstitute 4.2.1 (.NET Standard 2.0) in a Unity project, but I needed to include 3 more dependencies for it to work:

1. system.threading.tasks.extensions.4.5.3
2. system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.4.6.0
3. castle.core.4.4.0

Comment: worked for me! thanks! this shoud be the anwser! why using an old version

Comment: In 2018 the newer versions didn't work. But since this works, you should definitely go with the new version. Upvoted this one and added some reference in my answer to this one.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2020**

If you read this in 2020 or later, check the [answer from Rodrigo Eleuterio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58896527/511362) how to make this work with the latest version of NSubstitute.

**/end update**

I was able to make the 2.0.3 version work with Unity. The newer versions have additional dependencies which I could not make work in Unity, so it seems for now we're stuck with 2.0.3. So here is how I did it:

- Download 2.0.3 from the [NuGet Website](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSubstitute/2.0.3).
- Unzip the file and move the `lib/net35/NSubstitute.dll` into the `Plugins` folder of your project.
- In your test assembly definition, don't forget to reference it, otherwise it will not be found.

[image]

When you now reopen the project in Rider it should be found. Sometimes Unity acts up a little and doesn't seem to find the DLL. In this case re-importing the project can help.

Comment: Just a note, use the checkbox "override references" to show that list.