# error CS0433: The type ThreadLocal<T> exists in both NSubstitute and mscorlib

Tags: unity-game-engine, upgrade, nsubstitute

I upgraded from Unity 2019.2.21 to 2019.4.5.

Now I'm getting this error:

```
Library/PackageCache/com.unity.scriptablebuildpipeline@1.7.3/
Editor/Utilities/BuildLog.cs(51,9): error CS0433: The type 
'ThreadLocal<T>' exists in both 'NSubstitute, Version=0.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92dd2e9066daa5ca' and 'mscorlib, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

It's strange because everything worked fine in Unity 2019.2.21.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422962/unity3d-the-type-task-exist-in-both-unity-tasks-and-mscorelib) looks similar, but wasn't able to help me.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the package up to date?

Comment: I updated all my packages from Unity.  I added the NSubstitute.dll manually a long time ago, so unsure about that :/

Comment: Well both this `NSubstitute` and `mscorelib` seem to implement the same type so your package doesn't understand which one to reference .. why does the link you added not solve this?

Comment: I see.  That link recommends to 1.  Modify the scriptablebuildpipeline .asmdef file.  However, when I run Unity my changes to that file are overwritten.  Or 2., remove the offending package, which I don't think I can do (I believe scriptablebuildpipeline is used for addressables, which I use.)

Comment: Is it possible to switch to a newer NSubstitute? IIRC it used to define `ThreadLocal` for platforms that didn't support it, but more recent versions no longer require this.

Comment: Good idea, let me try that :)

Comment: I switched to NSubstitute 2.0.3, and that fixes the issue :). (When I play my Unity scene my Mac crashes, but I think that's a different issue.). If you chuck your comment in an answer then I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my `NSubstitute.dll` to version 2.0.3 as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57998516/1438809), which fixed the issue.

Apparently older versions of NSubstitute defined `ThreadLocal` themselves, which was causing my issue (thanks David Tchepak!).